# ThreeJS Loading a Texuture from a raw javascript ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

Given an Javascript ArrayBuffer with the binary data of a image and the extension (jpg, png , etc)
I would like to create a ThreeJS Texture (without doing any HTTP request or file load as I already have the binary information).

For instance suppose I have :

```
var binaryData = getBinaryData(); // this returns an ArrayBuffer with the image, for this example we assume is a PNG image.
var imageFormat = "png";
```

(and also we have the other texture properties as the wrap mode, mipmaps, etc)

How I can load the Texture ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you convert your array of binary data into a base64 string. Then you can attach it to an `Image` object and then use the `Image` object with a Three.js `Texture`.

```
// Convert the array of data into a base64 string
var stringData = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(jpgData));
var encodedData = window.btoa(stringData);
var dataURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + encodedData;

// Connect the image to the Texture
var texture = new THREE.Texture();

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {
    texture.image = image;
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
};
image.src = dataURI;
```

Here is the full code (the cat image is low resolution on purpose):

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var jpgData = new Uint8Array([255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,255,254,0,62,67,82,69,65,84,79,82,58,32,103,100,45,106,112,101,103,32,118,49,46,48,32,40,117,115,105,110,103,32,73,74,71,32,74,80,69,71,32,118,54,50,41,44,32,100,101,102,97,117,108,116,32,113,117,97,108,105,116,121,10,255,219,0,67,0,8,6,6,7,6,5,8,7,7,7,9,9,8,10,12,20,13,12,11,11,12,25,18,19,15,20,29,26,31,30,29,26,28,28,32,36,46,39,32,34,44,35,28,28,40,55,41,44,48,49,52,52,52,31,39,57,61,56,50,60,46,51,52,50,255,219,0,67,1,9,9,9,12,11,12,24,13,13,24,50,33,28,33,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,255,192,0,17,8,0,24,0,24,3,1,34,0,2,17,1,3,17,1,255,196,0,31,0,0,1,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,255,196,0,181,16,0,2,1,3,3,2,4,3,5,5,4,4,0,0,1,125,1,2,3,0,4,17,5,18,33,49,65,6,19,81,97,7,34,113,20,50,129,145,161,8,35,66,177,193,21,82,209,240,36,51,98,114,130,9,10,22,23,24,25,26,37,38,39,40,41,42,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,255,196,0,31,1,0,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,255,196,0,181,17,0,2,1,2,4,4,3,4,7,5,4,4,0,1,2,119,0,1,2,3,17,4,5,33,49,6,18,65,81,7,97,113,19,34,50,129,8,20,66,145,161,177,193,9,35,51,82,240,21,98,114,209,10,22,36,52,225,37,241,23,24,25,26,38,39,40,41,42,53,54,55,56,57,58,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,255,218,0,12,3,1,0,2,17,3,17,0,63,0,225,109,238,89,177,194,175,3,160,56,198,63,90,232,23,193,58,181,198,129,246,255,0,48,91,73,52,196,37,147,225,119,192,49,243,111,45,158,73,29,187,142,213,204,197,117,246,11,104,101,154,88,124,180,145,72,81,247,136,207,183,30,181,239,190,36,188,211,99,68,185,242,148,164,113,121,145,180,127,119,102,51,159,166,43,139,15,77,89,201,149,177,226,44,230,81,37,188,214,234,251,91,107,28,228,238,29,206,79,255,0,90,138,154,242,120,230,19,72,176,198,190,103,207,251,179,157,217,25,200,205,21,196,147,111,64,122,144,216,248,87,251,98,55,143,85,185,158,210,220,169,116,40,60,204,55,24,227,191,83,233,94,129,117,168,19,225,187,125,29,165,23,119,73,103,37,164,183,112,40,10,160,0,17,182,158,229,120,227,184,162,138,214,150,42,106,45,89,21,73,123,73,53,35,137,26,4,176,69,228,137,51,110,16,236,221,130,216,3,140,154,40,162,176,246,175,153,232,67,220,255,217]);


// Convert the array of data into a base64 string
var stringData = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(jpgData));
var encodedData = window.btoa(stringData);
var dataURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + encodedData;

// Connect the image to the Texture
var texture = new THREE.Texture();

var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {
 texture.image = image;
 texture.needsUpdate = true;
};
image.src = dataURI;


var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 1;

var render = function () {
 requestAnimationFrame( render );

 renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   body { margin: 0; }
   canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r70/three.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we are doing exactly as you explained but we need to load directly the raw binary data. To my knowlege that approach works for JPEG and PNG images. But what happens if you would like to load another texture in TGA or DDS ? In addition the conversion to a data URI causes an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @NicoRaf Then why did you accept this answer? The moment you do that, your question basically becomes invisible. Additionally, if I now ask the same question, the're a strong possibility they'll close it as duplicate and send me here.

Answer (score 3):

i am also looking for a way to load arraybuffer to texture directly. currently, we also create a local URL to workaround it. by following code.

```
const blob = new Blob([arraybuffer]);
let url =  window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: Great, this is also useful to load model from an arbitrary source like a file_picker or a ajax call!